# How do I add a designer verb to a control without disabling existing designer functionality?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a custom text box control derived from `TextBox`.

To add a designer verb I create a designer that I attach to my control, but doing this will disable all existing designer functionality in `System.Windows.Forms.Design.TextBoxDesigner` that is attached to the `TextBox` class.

The `TextBoxDesigner` class is set to `internal` so I can't derive my designer from that either.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there some other way to add design time functionality to a derived control without destroying the already existing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you find no other alternatives you could inherit without really inheriting.

```
class ExtendedTextboxDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public ExtendedTextboxDesigner()
    {
        var atts = (DesignerAttribute[])typeof(TextBox).GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DesignerAttribute),
            false);

        var designer = (ControlDesigner)Activator.CreateInstance(
            Type.GetType(atts[0].DesignerTypeName));
    }

    private ControlDesigner Base { get; set; }

    public override bool CanBeParentedTo(IDesigner parentDesigner)
    {
        return Base.CanBeParentedTo(parentDesigner);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This has the annoyance that you will need to override every method and property of `ControlDesigner`.

Comment: Yes, but this only works for the public members. A protected member cannot be accessed like this.

Comment: You could use reflection for that which is cumbersome, but as I stated, this is purely a last resort option.